# python check if word matches portion of key in a dictionary

Tags: python

Could someone help with this? I would like to do a partial search for a word in dictionary keys.

```
$ cat dic.py
dic={"pluto_123":"yes"}
print("pluto" in dic)

$python dic.py
False
```

You can see the result is False which is expected but instead, I need to get the result as True taking **pluto_123** contains **pluto**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

With your check, you need to have a key exactly called `pluto`. Since you don't have one, you got `False`.

You need to check if your substring is present in a key, for every key in your dictionary:

```py
>>> print(any("pluto" in key for key in dic))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but then you waste the capability of the dictionary to do a lookup in O(1).

```py
for key in dic:
   if "pluto" in key:
      print("found")
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that utilizes an extension of the `dict` class.

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def __contains__(self, item):
        for key in self.keys():
            if item in key:
                return True
        return False

d = MyDict()
d.update({"pluto_123":"yes"})

print("pluto" in d)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Keep in mind this will have a readability & performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new type of dict this way.

```
class NewDict(dict):
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return any(key in k  for k in self.keys())
        
dic=NewDict(pluto_123 ="yes", plu45="90")
```